# making a binary tree

Tags: java, jvm, binary-tree

Hi
I want to make a binary tree which is based -level,which means that nodes of first level will be create and then all the nodes of second level will be creat and then all the nodes of third level will be create ,...
for making a binary tree like above ,I used a list(data structure)
I want to know that JVM can remember the order of nodes or I must use list?
thanks

Comment: Do you have some example code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Using a List seems like a good choice. (Put all the level-1 nodes in a linked list; then run through that list, pulling off pairs of nodes, creating a level-2 node to be their parent, and putting that in a new list. Repeat.)

Comment: Meant to ask -- what do you mean by whether the JVM can remember the order of the nodes? If you use a List, isn't it the JVM implementing the list for you?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a data structure that maintains the links between your elements.  If you just had an array and created everything at level 1, then created a second array at level 2, the JVM won't remember for you the order that things were created.

In short, you're likely going to want to use a Linked List for something like that.

Comment: thanks,yes I used an array as a field for every node that will return the order of nodes till the special node.is it right?

Comment: also as I mentioned above, I store those nodes in a list!